# `http://sitename.com/http://sitename.com/page` works

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

working on a strange issue in codeigniter.

The `http://sitename.com/http://sitename.com/pagename` works and goes to `http://sitename.com/pagename`. should not it redirect to 4xx(404,403) page?

my base url is `http://sitename.com` .
It should redirect either to home page or a 404 page.

Comment: empty  `index` in config.php

Comment: Yes the variable is already empty  `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: you getting your url twice??

Comment: no, it is displaying once but 
`http://sitename.com/http://sitename.com/mypage` is same as 
`http://sitename.com/mypage` causing issue in seo and links

Comment: `http://sitename.com/http://sitename.com/pagename` in here your url repeated 2 times

Comment: Yes it gives me the same page. wondering if can be fixed with `.htaccess`?

Comment: post an answer check it

Answer (score 0):

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

.htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```